# How to add a certificate on a windows service

Tags: windows, delphi, soap, ssl

I have a custom soap-service for windows server which listens on a portnumber (for ex. 1024). When I make a call to this service using `http:// (ip or domain):1024` the service works well.

When I try to make the same call to `https:// (ip or domain):1024` I get the following response:

> SSL connection error
> Unable to make a secure connection to the server.
>   This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have.

When I try to connect to the same ip without the portnumber my IIS responds without any issue (I have a certificate installed).

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Does your program actually speak HTTPS? Don't immediately assume the problem is with the certificate; the error message lists multiple possible causes.

Comment: Have a look at Indy, which supports SSL. I use the RemObjects components and their SSL option, but at core they are using Indy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify:

a)-- Your delphi code is directly opening a socket and listening on a port

or

b)-- Your delphi code is hosted by IIS, and IIS is listening on a port

If it is 'a', then you need to add SSL support to your delphi app, so that your delphi app can speak SSL to clients. E.g. if you use Indy, or remote objects, or whatever, then your SSL work will happen at that level.

If it is 'b' then you go through the standard process of IIS SSL management (e.g. create a request file in IIS, then purchase a cert, then install the cert in IIS.... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299875 )